# 二次元配列の行・列の抽出

Tags: python

現在Pythonの自作モジュールを作成中です。
Pythonの自作モジュール内で、二次元配列の中の数値だけ取り出したいです。
これは動作確認用なのでこのプログラムは変えないで下の自作モジュールのプログラムだけ変えていただきたいです

```
import data_conduct as da
data = [["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"],
        ["A", 90, 35, 60, 40],
        ["B", 80, 25, 61, 35],
        ["C", 85, 40, 70, 45]]

begin = 1
end = 5
print(data)
```

上と下は別ファイルで、下が自作モジュール(data_conduct.py)です。
**data_conduct.py**

```
def find_max(data,begin,end):
    del data[0]
    print(data)
```

先程の二次元配列を自作モジュール内でこのように処理したいのですがどうすればいいのかわかりません。

```
 data = [[90, 35, 60, 40],
　　　　　[80, 25, 61, 35],
         [85, 40, 70, 45]]
```

**補足**

> def find_max(data,begin,end):の中の処理をどうにかしたいということでしょうか？ その場合、beginやendは何か意味がありますか？ ある場合はどのように使われるのでしょう？

def find_max(data,begin,end):の中の処理について
beginやendはindex値で、beginは二次元配列の中の1列目90,80,85、endは(end-1)列の40,32,45という風にbeginからend列まで取り出したいです。
beginやendの値が配列の範囲を超えていたり大小が逆だった場合のチェックは必要ないです。

Comment: `def find_max(data,begin,end):`の中の処理をどうにかしたいということでしょうか？ その場合、`begin`や`end`は何か意味がありますか？ ある場合はどのように使われるのでしょう？

Comment: そうです。beginやendはindex値で、beginは二次元配列の中の1列目Q2,90,80,85、endは(end-1)列のQ5,40,32,45という風にbeginからend列まで取り出したいです。

Comment: その場合、最初の行の`Q2`～`Q5`のデータが希望する結果の方に入っていないのは何故でしょう？ また`begin`や`end`の値が配列の範囲を超えていたり大小が逆だったりした場合のチェックを行いますか？

Comment: すみません。間違えてQ2やQ5を入れてしまったのですが、正しくは希望する結果の通りでbeginは１列目90,80,85、endは40,32,45です。beginやendの値が配列の範囲を超えていたり大小が逆だった場合のチェックは行わなくて大丈夫です。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで応答した内容を`def find_max(data,begin,end):`の処理として作るなら以下のようになるでしょう。
`del data[0]`に相当する部分も含めて1行の処理に出来ます。

```
def find_max(data,begin,end):
    data = [x[begin:end] for x in data[1:]]
    print(data)
```